# jQuery select parent li of current item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying and failing at selecting with jQuery the grandaprent `li` of my menu.

Tried many selectors, such as:

```
$(this).parents('li').find('a').addClass('current');
```

But the above doesnt select the furthest parent..

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a>
            <div class="sub">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to select **grandparent** of the `li a` that has the class `current`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closest()`, but as it starts with the current element, `closest('li')` won't work, so you'll have to find the closest UL, and then the closest LI :

```
$(this).closest('ul').closest('li')
```

Comment: @SMacFadyen - Seems to work just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rLSm/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi use following code that need to trigerred on click of your element having class current.
Code would be like.

```
$(".current").bind("click",function(event){
    var desiredElement = $(this).parents('li:first');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".current").parents('ul').parents('li').find('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).parent().closest("li").addClass('current');
```

Comment: explain your code also by editing it, make it more readable and easy